# System of equations with binary variables

Tags: analysis, binary

Is there any way to simplify solving system of equations, assuming that all variables are binary? All equations, however, are seen as equations with real (or, to make things simple, integer) variables. So what we have is just "normal" equation system, but we know that all variables can be either 0 or 1.

Can the solution be simplified in general case? In case of linear system? In some other special cases? I'm looking forward to any explanations as well as links to related material.